# Reinforcement learning a3c with multiple independent outputs

Tags: tensorflow

I am attempting to modify and implement googles pattern of the Asynchronous Advantage Actor Critic (A3C) model. There are plenty of examples online out there that have gotten me started but I am running into a issues attempting to expand the samples.

All of the examples I can find focus on pong as the example which has a state based output of left or right or stay still. What I am trying to expand this to is a system that also has a separate on off output. In the context of pong, it would be a boost to your speed.

The code I am basing my code on can be found [here](https://github.com/awjuliani/DeepRL-Agents/blob/master/A3C-Doom.ipynb). It is playing doom, but it still has the same left and right but also a fire button instead of stay still. I am looking at how I could modify this code such that fire was an independent action from movement.

I know I can easily add another separate output from the model so that the outputs would look something like this:

```
self.output = slim.fully_connected(rnn_out,a_size,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax,
    weights_initializer=normalized_columns_initializer(0.01),
    biases_initializer=None)
self.output2 = slim.fully_connected(rnn_out,1,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,
    weights_initializer=normalized_columns_initializer(0.01),
    biases_initializer=None)
```

The thing I am struggling with is how then do I have to modify the value output and redefine the loss function. The value is still tied to the combination of the two outputs. Or is there a separate value output for each of the independent output. I feel like it should still only be one output as the value, but I am unsure how I them use that one value and modify the loss function to take this into account.

I was thinking of adding a separate term to the loss function so that the calculation would look something like this:

```
self.actions_1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.int32)
self.actions_2 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.float32)
self.actions_onehot = tf.one_hot(self.actions_1,a_size,dtype=tf.float32)
self.target_v = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.float32)
self.advantages = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.float32)

self.responsible_outputs = tf.reduce_sum(self.output1 * self.actions_onehot, [1])
self.responsible_outputs_2 = tf.reduce_sum(self.output2 * self.actions_2, [1])

#Loss functions
self.value_loss = 0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(self.target_v - tf.reshape(self.value,[-1])))
self.entropy = - tf.reduce_sum(self.policy * tf.log(self.policy))
self.policy_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.log(self.responsible_outputs)*self.advantages) - 
    tf.reduce_sum(tf.log(self.responsible_outputs_2)*self.advantages)
self.loss = 0.5 * self.value_loss + self.policy_loss - self.entropy * 0.01
```

I am looking to know if I am on the right track here, or if there are resources or examples that I can expand off of.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the example you are mentioning don't need two output nodes. One output node with continuous output value is enough to solve. Also you should't use placeholder for advantage, but rather you should use for discounted reward.

```
self.discounted_reward = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.float32)
self.advantages = self.discounted_reward - self.value
```

Also while calculating the policy loss you have to use `tf.stop_gradient` to prevent the `value` node gradient feedback contribution for policy learning.

```
self.policy_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.log(self.responsible_outputs)*tf.stop_gradient(self.advantages))
```

Comment: In the example, there is three outputs left right and fire. I want to make fire independent of the movement so you can do both at one time. Can you show me an example of this as well? Thanks for the other tips as well.

Comment: here you can just keep fire on forever (use one output to move right/left), no need to use extra outputs.